# gpu and pytorch reproduce

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

I found that the model I built with pytorch was consistent over multiple training when there was plenty of gpu memory left.
Once there is less video memory left, the result of the run out will change, and there is no way to reproduce the previous run out result, why？
thank you

thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.